# What's the difference between these two?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

We have the following two sentences:

> We definitely are able to make something delicious.

And:

> We definitely are able of making something delicious.

What's the difference between these two? I can only see that the first one sounds more informal and does not use the contracted verb (making). Can someone point me to the answer?

Comment: The first is correct (although **definitely** would usually follow **are**). The second is wrong. It should read: **.....are capable of...**

Comment: Why exactly is it wrong? Is it just because I used able instead of capable?

Comment: Yes, it's not idiomatic. No native English speaker would use it.

Answer (score 1):

"capable is often used with "of" as can be seen in [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capable), particularly sense three

> having attributes (such as physical or mental power) required for performance or accomplishment
>
> > *is capable of intense concentration*

"able" just isn't used that wqay, as can be seen from [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/able). However one could use "able" in a sentence such as:

> We are definitely  able to mak something delicious.

I don't know why "capable" can be used with an of-construct, but "able" can't. However, that is how the words are used in my experience and according to dictionaries.